# ввести Строку,СИ

Tags: c

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <malloc.h>
void sort(char *words[],int size) {

    int n,m,code;
    char *temp;
    for(n=1; n<size; n++)
        for(m=0; m<size-n; m++) {
            code=strcmp(words[m],words[m+1]);
            if(code>0) {
                temp=words[m];
                words[m]=words[m+1];
                words[m+1]=temp;
            }
        }
    printf("\nsort:\n");
    for (n = 0; n < size; n++)
        printf("%s ",words[n] );
    }



int main() {

char *words[5];

char word[5][50];
int i;
for (i=0;i<5;i++){
   printf("slovo:");
    gets(word[i]);
    words[i]=word[i];
}

    int size =sizeof(words)/sizeof(char*);
    sort(words,size);

}
```

как можно вводить строку с помощью strtok,а не пословно как выше?(сортировка по алфавиту,но хотелось бы чтоб сразу строка вводилась)

Comment: эм... `scanf("%s")` ?

Comment: @pavel эмммм,нет,тут дело не в этом,пролема в том что,строку нужно разбить на слова с помощью strtok,я вот не оч понимаю,как это сделать

Comment: [Ловите](http://pastebin.com/6XBP0KZH). Это не strtok, но чем-то похоже и как по мне, так удобней.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<stdio.h>


int main()
{
  char buff[200];
  fgets(buff,200,stdin);
  char* token=strtok(buff," ");
  while(token)
  {
     printf("%s\n", token);
     token=strtok(NULL," ");
  }

 }
```